# Check if different / specific app is installed

Tags: progressive-web-apps

As far as I know, native apps are able to check the existence of specific foreign apps (via `context.getPackageManager();` or similar).

Am I mistaken or is this actually possible? And can I somehow achieve this with a PWA?